# Hadoop Streaming Multiple Files per Map Job

Tags: hadoop

I have a Hadoop streaming setup that works, however there is a bit of overhead when initializing the mappers which is done once per file, and since I am processing many files I notice I'm spending a lot of time in initialization.

Is there a way, without writing any Java, to specify that I want to reuse the same mapper instance for multiple files to amortize the initialization cost?

Comment: To clarify, it's my mapper script (written in perl) that has substantial initialization overhead, so I'm looking to reuse each script instance over many files.

Answer (score 0):

In `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/mapred-site.xml` add/edit the follow property

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks</name>
    <value>#</value>
</property>
```

The `#` can be set to a number to specify how many times the JVM is to be reused (default is 1), or set to -1 for no limit on the reuse amount.

It's also to specify it per job by setting the job configuration `mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks` to the desired value.

Comment: However, judging from top, it looks my mapper scripts are still being spawned frequently; in other words, now the JVM owners of my mapper scripts are persisting (which is good, I guess); but the initialization overhead I was referring to was in my mapper script itself.  Is there a way to reuse the *mapper script* over multiple files?

Comment: If you are doing initialization in the `map` function, override the `setup` function and do the initialization in there. There is also a `cleanup` function that can be overridden. `setup` and `cleanup` will only be called once per mapper instance (pretty much once per JVM in this context), while the `map` function will be called as many times as the JVM can be used. Moving anything you can to `setup` may improve performance.

Comment: I'm using Hadoop streaming; can I achieve my goal via configuration without writing Java?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used hadoop streaming yet so I can't answer on that. (I wrote my last comment before noticing you were using perl scripts.)